# Docker compose: bind multiple hosts to dynamic container's IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I declare my service in `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```
wildfly:
  image: "myrepo/wildfly:latest"
  hostname: wildfly
```

So, compose adds entry to /etc/hosts:

```
172.18.0.4      wildfly
```

Where `172.18.0.4` is generated automatically by docker.

But I need to bind `some.host.name` to this generated IP in `/etc/hosts` to have multiple entries in /etc/hosts:

```
172.18.0.4      wildfly
172.18.0.4      some.host.name
```

How can I do that?

I tried to use `extra_hosts` syntax, but in `docker-compose.yml` I have no idea what IP will be assigned to container.

Have anybody faced the similar problem?

Comment: what version of docker are you using? `docker version`

Comment: Hi, Tarun! `17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72`

Comment: I've temporary added aliases in `networks` to `some.host.name` domain sections for two `wildfly` services. Now in one container docker added desired entry in `/etc/hosts` but in second - did not ) Strange, but `some.host.name` is resolved to corresponding container's IPs correctly. Some kind of magic for me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should version '3' format of the compose which supports aliases. Since you are already using a supported docker version

```
version: '3'
services:
  wildfly:
    image: "myrepo/wildfly:latest"
    hostname: wildfly
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - some.host.name
```

This won't add host entries since docker now uses its own internal DNS server. If you need to use multiple compose files to be able to reach the services. Then you should create an external network

```
docker network create commonnet
```

And then use below in your compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  wildfly:
    image: "myrepo/wildfly:latest"
    hostname: wildfly
    networks:
      commonnet:
        aliases:
          - some.host.name
networks:
  commonnet:
    external: true
```

Comment: Thx, @TarunLalwani! Your answer helped me a lot